# In larger companies, what is the difference between Marketing and Business Development units?

Tags: job-description

I found various online resources giving an answer to this question, however, it is not clear to me what organizations actually do in practice.

I have seen or heard of companies where the functions of both are done by either Marketing, and where Business Development unit doesn't exist.

Could it be more precise to say that Business Development is more about B2B sales generation, whereas Marketing is more B2C sales generation?
(I have never seen or heard of Business Development being tasked to drive sales from end customers / B2C)

Answer (score 6):

Marketing is doing things to promote the sales process.  This includes advertising, events like trade shows, special promotions (buy two get third free, but only before June first), etc.  All these things are ultimately intended to drive sales.

Business development is building the business other ways than just driving sales.  This could include alliances with other companies, buying other companies or getting acquired by them, etc.  For example, if your product A works together with another type of product B that you don't make, you might work with a company that makes B to offer a bundled deal to both your end customers, or special support built into your A for that specific brand of B, and vice versa.  This gives both your companies advantages in competing in their respective spaces.

Some things, like setting up new distribution channels could be considered marketing or business development, depending on how the company is structured.